# Fancybox close button is cut off when using Foundation 3 and CSS border-box

Tags: css, fancybox, fancybox-2, border-box

When using box-sizing: border-box, it causes the "close" button to be cut off. This is especially the case when using Foundation 3 by Zurb.

The code that seems to cause issues for fancybox is this:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now, maybe the author needs to take border-box into consideration when doing the calcs, but I'd like to know if there's an easy way to override the behavior with CSS.

Here's a Fiddle that demonstrates what's happening. You can see how the close button gets cut off. http://jsfiddle.net/jonthomas/SxZuR/4/

Also, here's the issue on github: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/311

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The author of the plugin provided the CSS necessary to fix this](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/311). Use the following CSS to force fancybox and all of it's child elements to use content-box for box-sizing.

```
.fancybox-wrap, .fancybox-wrap * {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}​
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonthomas/ut93u/2/

He also mentions to make sure you have the latest code. I have 2.0.6 and the above code fixes the issue fine. However you can always grab the latest code here: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/zipball/master

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the solution. A great help.
One thing though. In my installation fancybox-wrap is an ID, not a CLASS. 
So I use:

```css
#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-wrap * {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the jsfiddle and the issue doesn't show up in Firefox (14.0.1) but in Chrome (20.0.1132.57 m)

The workaround I found is adding this CSS inline declaration (AFTER the fancybox css file is loaded):

```
.fancybox-wrap {
 overflow: visible !important;
}
```

**NOTE** : this for fancybox v2.0.6+